# adobe flex datagrid selectable columns

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, selectable

I'm trying to make a Flex (Advanced)DataGrid component with some mechanism where the user can toggle the visibility of the columns.  I've crudely implemented this by reading in the columns into the right-click menu, and when a column name is selected here, the visibility is toggled.  It works, but it's not the most elegant solution.

Specifically, I'm trying to emulate the "datagrid" that Mozilla Thunderbird uses to display emails.  Here is an image:

[image: thunderbird_datagrid.png]

In the upper right, there is an icon over the scroll bar.  If there is no scrollbar, the icon remains in the same place.  When clicking the icon, it opens up a menu that shows all the possible columns, with the visible ones having a check mark next to them, like this:

[image: thunderbird_select_columns.png]

Also, the scroll bar always appears under this button, never "pushing" it over into it's own column.

I'd like to re-create this in Flex.  I believe the menu part and creating a column with a button headerRenderer is easy enough.  But I can't figure out how (if at all possible) to do this with the scrollbar, because the scrollbar always seems to be "its own column".  Any ideas or help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

- Ian

Comment: Hi Ian,
I've done a lot of work with ADG myself and found that for getting this kind of control your going to end up having to create an extension of ADG if you haven't already and will need to override some of the methods for example look at the AS3 language reference protected methods: drawColumnBackground, drawHeaderBackground, also to note you may be able to cheat this if you use the last column before the scrollbar as the container to put the PopupMenu into and just have it drawn outside of it's width and turn off clipping.

Answer (score 1):

One dirty solution comes to mind. Create a component based on Canvas, then add an AdvancedDataGrid by overriding createChildren. Override updateDisplayList as well and add a button like the one in Thunderbird to the upper right of the Canvas. This will cause the button to appear over the DataGrid. Problemo solved?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like an interesting solution.  I'll probably try it out.  Right now, my dirty solution consists of putting a Button and a List into a VBox to act as my scrollbar column.  The Button is the same height as the ADG headerHeight.  The List and the ADG are bound to the same data provider, but the list does not show any labels for the items.  So if the ADG doesn't need scrolling it works nice.  If it does, I scroll the ADG based on scrolling the list.

Comment: It actually works pretty nice with the exception of mouseOver highlighting when there is no scrollbar, i.e., when you mouseOver an item in the ADG, the corresponding item in the List is not highlighted as well, so it looks a little funny.  I'm thinking your solution might help avoid that.

Comment: If it worked do post a screenshot and code if you don't mind. And select this as correct answer  ;-)